# Rotating camera stream with TextureView crops the image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, textureview

The camera in the device that I am using returns rotated image (landscape 16:9). In order to acquire stream I use [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) API and for projection I use [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView). `TextureView` is fixed size. When I try to rotate it using `Matrix`it results in cropped image.

Here is what I have before the rotation:

[image]

Then I rotate it and adjust `TextureView` size like that:

```
private fun updateTransform() {
    val matrix = Matrix()
    val centerX = textureView.width / 2f
    val centerY = textureView.height / 2f
    matrix.postRotate(90.toFloat(), centerX, centerY)
    textureView.setTransform(matrix)
    textureView.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(textureView.width, textureView.height)
}
```

That results in the following image:

[image]

I'd like the image to be stretched to fill `TextureView`. Important to note is that I don't need to consider device rotation because it's always portrait. I am also programming for one device only so I don't need to consider different camera types etc.

How can I rotate the image without cropping it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This transformation fixed my problem:

```
import android.graphics.Matrix


private fun transformTexture() {
    val adjustment = Matrix()
    val centerX = textureView.width / 2f
    val centerY = textureView.height / 2f

    val scalex = textureView.width.toFloat() / textureView.height.toFloat()
    val scaley = textureView.height.toFloat() / textureView.width.toFloat()

    adjustment.postRotate(90F, centerX, centerY)
    adjustment.postScale(scalex, scaley, centerX, centerY)

    textureView.setTransform(adjustment)
}
```